# What is process apfsd?

Tags: sleep-wake, launchd

It shows in Activity Monitor as "preventing sleep." I have occasion to check that list of processes preventing sleep fairly often, and I don't recall seeing that before. I would guess that it might have something to do with Apple File System, perhaps a daemon started by launchd, but *I can find no reference to it anywhere through Google searches*.
I'm wondering if it's what is preventing my iMac (macOS 10.15.3) from sleeping or if it's just a red herring. If it is something necessary for APFS, I'm afraid to experiment by stopping the process for fear that the file system could become corrupted.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372072/is-there-a-way-to-force-apfsd-to-defragment-all-the-files-on-a-disk